# Redux form, where is VALUES coming from?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

So basically I'm trying to follow the following example and implement it onto my project. But I am confused, as you can see when `WizardFormThirdPage.js` is submitted, the function `showResults` is called. When I look at `showResults.js` it has values passed in, but I don't know where that is coming from or how the values for the form data is gotten, can someone explain it to me?

https://codesandbox.io/s/0Qzz3843

Answer (score 1):

In all three WizardForm pages, `onSubmit` is not provided by React, but a function overriden by Redux-form: https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/docs/api/reduxform.md/#-code-onsubmit-function-code-optional-. It provides several parameters, among them is `values`, which consists of all values in form `wizard`.

So in page 1 and 2, handler for `onSubmit` is function `nextPage` which neglects all parameters, and for page 3, the handler `showResults` only takes parameter `values`.

You can play around by modifying function `showResults`:

```
export default (async function showResults(...args) {
  await sleep(500); // simulate server latency
  window.alert(JSON.stringify(args));
});
```

which will display all parameters as shown in the link above.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Redux dev tools, you can see that all values that belongs to same form (like in this example wizard form' are added to wizard.values property. That property get's returned on handleSubmit and passed down to showResults.
It's writen as

```
<WizardForm onSubmit={showResults} />
```

and that showResults get that values property,
it can also be writen as

```
<WizardForm onSubmit={(values)=>showResults(values)} />
```

maybe that is bit clearer way to do it.

and im guesing that handleSubmit (from redux-form) takes values from redux store and do something like this

```
handleSubmit=(someValues)=>{
  // some your property that handles values
  this.props.yourOnSubmit(someValues);
}
```

where handleSubmit just use your onSubmit like a callback function with values argument and calls it with values.

Comment: I'm using redux dev tools, but when i input data I dont see anything get inputted to the state, see this for my code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55230669/storing-multiple-page-form-in-redux-store